# Setting up a primary key attribute through sequelize-cli

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

I'm using `npx sequelize model:create --name Satpam --attributes name:string,email:string,password:string` to create a model called `Satpam` and its migration. It created a model and a migration like below:

`models/satpam.js`

```js
'use strict';
const {
  Model
} = require('sequelize');
module.exports = (sequelize, DataTypes) => {
  class Satpam extends Model {
    /**
     * Helper method for defining associations.
     * This method is not a part of Sequelize lifecycle.
     * The `models/index` file will call this method automatically.
     */
    static associate(models) {
      // define association here
    }
  };
  Satpam.init({
    name: DataTypes.STRING,
    email: DataTypes.STRING,
    password: DataTypes.STRING
  }, {
    sequelize,
    modelName: 'Satpam',
  });
  return Satpam;
};
```

`migrations/20210417003647-create-satpam.js`

```js
'use strict';
module.exports = {
  up: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.createTable('Satpams', {
      id: {
        allowNull: false,
        autoIncrement: true,
        primaryKey: true,
        type: Sequelize.INTEGER
      },
      name: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      email: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      password: {
        type: Sequelize.STRING
      },
      createdAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      },
      updatedAt: {
        allowNull: false,
        type: Sequelize.DATE
      }
    });
  },
  down: async (queryInterface, Sequelize) => {
    await queryInterface.dropTable('Satpams');
  }
};
```

As you can see above, `sequelize` somehow adds `id` as its own primary key in the actual database. But I want to set the email attribute as the primary key. I have googled around and some people say that I have to only modify the `models/satpam.js`, but I doubted it, I think we also have to change the migrations as it reflects the actual database? but I guess it's a bad idea to change the migrations file as it is autogenerated?

Is there any fancy way to just provide every detail about the primary key, foreign key, etc through the `sequelize-cli` arguments?